SQL query - extracting the MIN and MAX from 2 columns
New to SQL and been doing beginner queries successfully. I am now trying to apply it to real life situations but am stuck on this particular problem:
I have a database for our family budget where myself and my wife have several accounts for different uses i.e. food, school expenses etc. From this, I am trying to extract what our balances for them at any given time (while it is easiest to just log in to our bank accounts, I wanted to see how I can do this in SQL as a learning exercise).
Our database looks like this:



Buyer
Date of Transaction
Bank Account
Transaction Amount
Bank Account Balance After Transaction




Mum
05/06/24
1
$3
$32


Dad
05/06/24
1
$2
$30


Dad
05/06/24
2
$10
$10


Mum
03/06/24
1
$5
$35


Mum
02/06/24
1
$10
$40



This would mean that before 2nd of June 2024, we started off with $50 in our Bank Account 1. Bought $10 worth from it, and ended with a balance of $40 after that transaction. Then after more transactions, we end up with a balance of $30 on 5th of June 2024.
Unfortunately, the dates do not have timestamps and any transaction on that date will not necessarily be in order of occurrence in the database (as above, considering the balance of Bank Account 1 the $2 transaction should be the last one to have occurred as it is the one with the lowest balance)
This is what I want the results to look like:



Bank Account
Current Balance




1
$30


2
$10



To me it seems like I need to take the MAX Date and find the MIN value that occurred that date (I have not taken in account deposits yet, but that is a problem I will tackle later). However, in trying this I can't seem to group them together and get a bigger list than 2 results. I also then get errors when I play around with MIN and MAX's.
Any assistance for a noob in learning is appreciated!

"Unfortunately, the dates do not have timestamps" - can you redesign your database so it does store them?

This is a type of query that I think can be instructively solved with a "two step" approach - first to get the dates of interest, second to get the balances of interest.
You solve the first step with a Max query:
select Account, Max(TransDate) as MaxTransDate
from #Table1
group by Account

Result of this initial step is two rows with account and date:



Account
MaxTransDate




1
2024-06-05


2
2024-06-05



This gives you the account and max date. But how to "combine" this in the next step, well you just use the first result as part of your second query ... imagine it as a query of a query, or an imaginary table that you join with.
So, next we continue with:
select 
    t1.Account, 
    min(t1.RemainingBalance) as RemainingBalance
from
    #Table1 t1
    inner join (
        -- -------------------------------------------
        select Account, Max(TransDate) as MaxTransDate
        from #Table1
        group by Account
        -- -------------------------------------------
        ) t2
    on t1.Account = t2.Account
    and t1.TransDate = t2.MaxTransDate
group by 
    t1.Account

I have tried to make it very clear how the "first query" becomes part of the completed query - its there in the middle!
This is merely to show one way of solving this with "basic principles", using aggregate queries such as Max and Min - as you were asking about. There's plenty of things that could be said but you learn by doing so I think you have lots to work with in a project like this and you will learn as you go. I would advise you to very quickly include the "deposits" in your data, as any day where you add money to the bank account, the final balance may not be the lowest balance.

Well, if it is just for a learning exercise then we will leave some serious design issues aside and focus on sample data and expected result.
One of the options to do it is using Min() Over() and Max() Over() analytic functions with Case expreessions. The idea is to select all columns except BALANCE from your table as they are and the BALANCE column having it's value just if the TRANSACTION_DATE is equal to max date (per bank account) AND BALANCE is equal to min balance (per bank account). All other rows would have null value in BALANCE column. Then, if you Select all rows Where BALANCE Is Not Null from that (inner) query - you'll get your expected result. More comments in code.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (BUYER, TRANSACTION_DATE, BANK_ACCOUNT, AMOUNT, BALANCE) AS
      ( Select 'Mum', DATE '2024-06-05', 1,  3, 32 From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Dad', DATE '2024-06-05', 1,  2, 30 From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Dad', DATE '2024-06-05', 2, 10, 10 From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Mum', DATE '2024-06-03', 1,  5, 35 From Dual Union All 
        Select 'Mum', DATE '2024-06-02', 1, 10, 40 From Dual 
      )

--    S Q L :
SELECT  *
FROM    ( Select    BUYER,  TRANSACTION_DATE, BANK_ACCOUNT, AMOUNT, 
        -- You said: "To me it seems like I need to take the MAX Date and find the MIN value that occurred that date"
        -- ... below Case expression will give the value to BALANCE column  just in the rows with those Max/Min conditions satisfied
                    Case When TRANSACTION_DATE = Max(TRANSACTION_DATE) Over(Partition By BANK_ACCOUNT) And 
                              BALANCE = Min(BALANCE) Over(Partition By BANK_ACCOUNT)
                         Then BALANCE
                    End as BALANCE
          From      tbl
        ) 
WHERE   BALANCE Is Not Null  -- excludes rows with empty BALANCE column

... above code selects all columns (*) but you can select just those that you need: (BANK_ACCOUNT, BALANCE)
/*    R e s u l t :
BUYER TRANSACTION_DATE BANK_ACCOUNT     AMOUNT    BALANCE
----- ---------------- ------------ ---------- ----------
Dad   05.06.24                    1          2         30
Dad   05.06.24                    2         10         10  */

NOTE:
Try to rethink about issues that you will face with such organized data. This depends on BALANCE column which shouldn't exist as such but calculated as a consequence of adding and spending bank account's fond. Imagine that your dad forgot to tell you that he spent $10 like two weeks ago - how would that affect your balance column values. And that is just a silly simple issue.
